# Show API response on fragment on submit

Tags: android, kotlin

When I search on my searchview I want to send the search value to the api that will give back a response that I want to be showed on the fragment. So when I submit my search I want to show the fragment with the response! I tried to make a function to render the fragment but I think im doing it completly wrong...
Im begginer and this is for a project for school, thank you for help!

**SearchView**

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)

    val manager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
    val searchView = searchItem?.actionView as SearchView

    searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(componentName))

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object: SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            searchView.clearFocus()
            searchView.setQuery("",false)
            searchItem.collapseActionView()
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
    return true
}
```

**Data Class**

```
 data class SearchPost(val searchKey: String)
```

**Fragment**

```
  class SendFragment : Fragment() {

var newList: MutableList<News> = mutableListOf<News>()

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = SendFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: SendViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_searched, container, false)
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SendViewModel::class.java)



    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)


    // TODO: Use the ViewModel

    val searchedObserver = Observer<List<News>>
    {
        // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
            newList -> recyclerView.adapter = NewsAdapter(newList,this.context!!)

    }

    viewModel.getNewSearched().observe(this, searchedObserver)

}
 }
```

**Fragment View Model**

```
 class SendViewModel : ViewModel() {

// TODO: Implement the ViewModel

private var newList: MutableLiveData<List<News>> = MutableLiveData()



fun getNewSearched(): MutableLiveData<List<News>>
{

    searchedNew()

    return newList;

}

private fun searchedNew()
{
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.78:3000")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val api = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
    val searchPost = SearchPost("this is want to be the query")
    api.sendSearch(searchPost).enqueue(object : Callback<List<News>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<News>>, response: Response<List<News>>) {
            newList.value=(response.body()!!)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<News>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("fail", "onFailure:")
        }
    })

}
 }
```

**Api interface**

```
interface ApiService {
@POST("/search")
fun sendSearch(@Body searchPost: SearchPost): Call<List<News>>


  }
```

Comment: It doesn't help to post all your code without stating what is wrong or what is the current behaviour. But from what i can see, it seems like you are not using `query` in `onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?)`.

Comment: I explained! What is wrong its when i submit i dont get the response from the searched... Thats why im asking how to  send the query to the retrofit and show the fragment that will show the response from the api when i submit

Comment: Is your search view is in fragment or in activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe view model like this :

```
 viewModel.getNewSearched().observe(this, Observer<MutableList<List<News>>> {
      myNewsData ->
        Log.d("print my data", myNewsData) // first try to print this data whether data is coming or not
      recyclerView.adapter = NewsAdapter( myNewsData ,this.context!!)
    })
```

Initialize your searchView :

```
private fun initSearchView() {
    search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(object :
        androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(newText: String?): Boolean {
            viewMode.getNewSearched()  // call your api here

            return false  // don,t change it to true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

At last I thing you should pass the text to viewmodel which you want to search

```
override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {

  viewMode.getNewSearched(query)
```

In side viewmodel  :

```
fun getNewSearched(textYouWantToSearch :String): MutableLiveData<List<News>>
{
    searchedNew(textYouWantToSearch) // same pass in searchedNew() else your data class is always blank
    return newList;
}
```

In my understanding your data class which you are passing in your retrofit call is always blank because you are not passing any value from anywhere you should use query string of your search method and try to pass as an parameter.

Comment: Why is this red? - https://prnt.sc/qjoqcn
Check this one too - https://prnt.sc/qjoqi4

Comment: just try to re build  project also let me know when you are running  project are you getting  compiled  time error?. Also accept  if my answer helped you and upvote. if still stuck tell me i will help you

Comment: I did it. But still red saying unknown reference.

Comment: can you show me full  of viewmodel and fragment according  me its studio bug but lets see

Comment: you are not instantiate your viewmodel and directly trying to access method from your viewmodel : do this      viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SendViewModel::class.java)  and then call the method viewModel.getNewSearched() it will work for sure.

Comment: val viewModel = SendViewModel()  i instastied like this but when i search the app crashes

Comment: So, I think it crashes because my endpoint takes too long to give an answer. I checked on cmd and my console log on the endpoint answered after 20 secs.

Comment: bro remove that /  before  post method and make sure you have that / at end of base url never put /  before any retrofit method

Comment: I removed. I console loged my req.body too see the posted search and it shows this {}

Comment: means your api don't have any data. But now its not crashing right. Upvote and accept if my answer helped you.

Comment: It's REQ.body not RES.body. I think my app is not sending anything.